# Maximo automatisation script to change statut of workorder

Tags: maximo

I have created a non-persistent attribute in my WoActivity table named VDS_COMPLETE. it is a bool that get changed by a checkbox in one of my application.

I am trying to make a automatisation script in Python to change the status of every task a work order that have been check when I save the WorkOrder.

I don't know why it isn't working but I'm pretty sure I'm close to the answer...
Do you have an idea why it isn't working? I know that I have code in comments, I have done a few experimentations...

```
from psdi.mbo import MboConstants
from psdi.server import MXServer

mxServer = MXServer.getMXServer()
userInfo = mxServer.getUserInfo(user)

mboSet = mxServer.getMboSet("WORKORDER")
#where1 = "wonum = :wonum"
#mboSet .setWhere(where1)

#mboSet.reset()

workorderSet = mboSet.getMbo(0).getMboSet("WOACTIVITY", "STATUS NOT IN ('FERME' , 'ANNULE' , 'COMPLETE' , 'ATTDOC')")
#where2 = "STATUS NOT IN ('FERME' , 'ANNULE' , 'COMPLETE' , 'ATTDOC')"
#workorderSet.setWhere(where2)


if workorderSet.count() > 0:
    for x in range(0,workorderSet.count()):
        if workorderSet.getString("VDS_COMPLETE") == 1:
            workorder = workorderSet.getMbo(x)
            workorder.changeStatus("COMPLETE",MXServer.getMXServer().getDate(), u"Script d'automatisation", MboConstants.NOACCESSCHECK)

workorderSet.save()
workorderSet.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your two biggest mistakes here are 1. trying to get your boolean field (VDS_COMPLETE) off the set (meaning off of the collection of records, like the whole table) instead of off of the MBO (meaning an actual record, one entry in the table) and 2. getting your set of data fresh from the database (via that MXServer call) which means using the previously saved data instead of getting your data set from the screen where the pending changes have actually been made (and remember that non-persistent fields do not get saved to the database).

There are some other problems with this script too, like your use of "count()" in your for loop (or even more than once at all) which is an expensive operation, and the way you are currently (though this may be a result of your debugging) not filtering the work order set before grabbing the first work order (meaning you get a random work order from the table) and then doing a dynamic relationship off of that record (instead of using a normal relationship or skipping the relationship altogether and using just a "where" clause), even though that relationship likely already exists.

Here is a Stack Overflow describing in more detail about relationships and "where" clauses in Maximo: [Describe relationship in maximo 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29114531/describe-relationship-in-maximo-7-5/29147577)

This question also has *some* more information about getting data from the screen versus new from the database: [Adding a new row to another table using java in Maximo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763701/adding-a-new-row-to-another-table-using-java-in-maximo/27780168)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the answer on your 2nd link. is MboRemote an object to get the information from the active screen?

Comment: MboRemote is *the* object you use for interacting with a row of data period. Regardless of where it came from. That's Maximo coding 101. How you get the MboRemote determines if it is a fresh query from the database, or from the in-memory cache (which often means what is on the screen and not yet in the database). Plus, you should realize that automation scripts start with a reference to an MboRemote, the specific MboRemote that is doing whatever action you hooked your automation script into (save, init, etc.) and so is often the very object you want to do your work on already.